# Removing a MovieClip and replacing with another in Flash AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, textures, movieclip

I have this simple code which removes a MovieClip, then assigns the object a new MovieClip. For some reason it re-adds the old clip underneath the new one. If I delete the old clip, the second one can't be added.

```
public function addAnimation(clip:Class):void 
        {

            _texture.parent.removeChild(_texture);

            var effect:MovieClip = new clip();

            texture.addChild(effect as MovieClip);

            //sync up points
            _texture.x = _body.GetPosition().x * Constants.PIXELS_TO_METRE;
            _texture.y = _body.GetPosition().y * Constants.PIXELS_TO_METRE;

            _texture = texture;
            addChild(texture);

            updateTexture();

        }
```

I would like to be able to delete a clip, and then assign it a new one. I've tried all kinds of variations and re-ordering the code, breaking into different functions etc, but I've reached a impass with this one.

Comment: what is `texture` here `texture.addChild(effect as MovieClip);`? seems like you're adding new clips there without removing old ones

Answer (score 0):

You code example is not clear:

1. what is the variable _texture and what is texture.
2. you can't remove a movieclip from itself `_texture.parent.removeChild(_texture);`

Maybe you mean something like:

```
private var _texture: MovieClip;
public function addAnimation(clip:Class):void 
{
    // remove previously added texture
    if (_texture) {
        removeChild(_texture);
    }

    // create new texture
    _texture = new clip();


    //sync up points
     _texture.x = _body.GetPosition().x * Constants.PIXELS_TO_METRE;
     _texture.y = _body.GetPosition().y * Constants.PIXELS_TO_METRE;

     addChild(_texture);
     updateTexture();

 }
```

Comment: `_texture.parent.removeChild(_texture);` is not removing `_texture` from itself, but from its `.parent`, which is fine.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your code sample, you are adding new children to your `texture` without removing the old ones. This should solve the problem.

```
var effect:MovieClip = new clip();
texture.removeChildren(0, texture.numChildren - 1);
texture.addChild(effect as MovieClip);
```